# Is it possible to download CrateDB results in CSV file?

Tags: cratedb

I need to query the database, and drop the results in a csv file.

I remember I did this with sql server, is it possible to do this CrateDB?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CrateDB's `crash` shell supports various different output formats, including `csv`.

Example:

`crash --format csv -c 'select * from sys.cluster' > sys_cluster.csv`

See https://crate.io/docs/reference/crash for details.

Comment: Thx for pointing me to the correct direction, I did not read that part of the docs, next time I will pay more attention... kind regards

Answer (score 1):

Of course yes, where are u getting stuck?

You can find the official github repository of examples: [crate/crate-sample-apps](https://github.com/crate/crate-sample-apps), where cratedb is used. You can use this as a baseline to understand crate.

And, you can easily convert the values from crate to a CSV format using various language specific libraries. For example, in python you can use [csv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html).